# Memory Stream convert to Byte

Tags: c#

I'm retrieving image from DB using Stream. Need someone to help me to convert to byte. 
My code.

```
//connection.Open();

string sql = "SELECT Photo FROM ImageTable WHERE TagId = @ID";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", tagid);

connection.Open();

object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

try
{
    return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

before I return I need to change to byte. Someone please help.

Comment: 'byte' usually means an integer type taking values from 0 to 255. Are you sure you want to convert your image to that?

Comment: do you know what is the format of the image stored in SQL? PS, you may want to remove your DB connection details from the post

Comment: Yacoder - i googled and found most of the code they changed to byte..so just wanna try whether it works for me. Do you have any other better idea.
StaWho - its on varbinary(MAX)...db connection removed...

Comment: @chinna no, not the SQL field type, the actual format of the bitmap. The picture must have had some format (BMP, PNG, TGA etc) before it was stored in the DB

Comment: can you change your sa password now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is what you really want, but since the question is how to convert `MemoryStream` to `byte[]`:

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```